# Problemas com acentuação e HTML com Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Galera, estou criando um Microsoft Bot para o Messenger, mas estou com problemas com a acentuação nos textos e o html está sendo exibido na resposta.

Código:

```
   switch (session.message.text) {

    case 'Contato':

        session.send("<h3>Aqui estão alguns meios de contato:</h3><br>" +
            " <strong>Email:</strong> contato@cadabrapublicidade.com.br <br>" +
            " <strong>Telefone 1:</strong> (35) 3435-5922 <br>" +
            " <strong>Telefone 2:</strong> (35) 3435-3635 <br>" +
            " <h3>Endereço:</h3> <br>" +
            " <strong>Unidade 1:</strong> Praça Presidente Vargas, n°62, Sala 11 – Centro, Extrema MG <br>" +
            " <strong>Unidade 2:</strong> Avenida Salvador Markowicz, n°135, sala 403 – Edifício Carraro Tower – Bragança Paulista SP <br>" +
            " <strong>Visite nosso site:</strong> www.cadabrapublicidade.com.br");
        break;




   bot.dialog('showProducts', function (session) {
   var msg = new builder.Message(session);
   msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
   msg.attachments([

    new builder.HeroCard(session)
        .title("Contato")
        .subtitle("Entre em contato Conosco!")
        .text("")
        .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, 'http://cadabrapublicidade.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/contato_cadabra_publicidade.jpg')])
        .buttons([builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Contato', "Ver mais")]),
```

Como ele Exibe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `session` vem de onde?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, Lucas.

Comment: Existe algum UTF-8 nesse arquivo?

Comment: Eu tentei fazer a instalação do pacote uft8 pelo NPM, e chamei com o require no app.js: var utf8 = require('utf8');
Mas mesmo assim não funcionou :(

Comment: Engraçado é que se eu executar outro projeto pelo terminal com o comando: "node app.js"  sem utilizar o Visual Studio, ele funciona normal.

Comment: O problema está no projeto com o Visual Studio. Utilizo ele para fazer o deploy para o Azure com mais facilidade.

Comment: Já tentou a `iso-8859-1`?

Comment: Sim, tbm não funcionou.

Comment: Está dando erro ao instalar alguns pacotes via npm.
npm WARN bot-gundalf-novo@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN bot-gundalf-novo@0.0.0 No license field.

Comment: Tentei colocar a licença, mas nenhuma funciona.

Comment: Então galera, resolvi o problema dos acentos configurando o login e senha do ftp no azure, em seguida, fiz o deploy do bot sem criar outro projeto no Visual Studio, apenas utilizando o sublime msm para codificar. O outro problema era o HTML ser exibido junto com o texto no messenger... Provavelmente o messenger não aceita código HTML, em outros apps, (Como o Teams por exemplo) funciona normal. Para formatar o texto no messenger, vou ter que buscar outra forma.

Vlw Galera!